# Canvas animation performance optimization. Is there overhead calling 'this'?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am optimizing an HTML5 canvas animation.

The structure looks like this:

```
Animation = {
     //Cache constant variables
    cache : {
            var1 : 1,
            var2 : 2,
            var3 : 3
    },
    render : function(){
      //render to canvas

   }

}
```

Within the render function I am calling `this.cache.var1`, `this.cache.var2` etc... multiple times throughout and performing various calculations on them.

What I want to know is if calling `this` repeatedly during a single loop carries significant overhead, if so how best to optimize this?

Should I simply store a local copy within the render loop (`self=this;`) and work from `self`, Should I look at minimizing the various repeated calculations, breaking them down into various parts, storing them as local variable within the loops and work from those?

Any opinions are welcome.

Note:  I am aware this might be considered micro-optimization but when dealing with heavy animation processing I really would like to squeeze every last drop I can get.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) Beware premature optimization (particularly when you're not picking algorithms, but just variations in code) :: b) It's easy enough for you to test this yourself (and discover that it makes no measurable difference).

Comment: The actual drawing probably takes far longer than accessing properties.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz, if that is indeed the case, please retype it as an answer and I will gladly accept it.  With regards to testing myself, my apologies, if I knew how to, I would have done so.  Anyway, thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Any opinions are welcome.*

You don't want opinions, you want hard data! :) To whit:

### http://jsperf.com/this-versus-closure

```
Anim1 = {
   cache:  { var1:1, var2:2, var3:3 },
   render: function(){
     return this.cache.var1 + this.cache.var2 + this.cache.var3;
   }
};

AnimMaker = function(){
  var cache = { var1:1, var2:2, var3:3 };
  this.render = function(){
    return cache.var1 + cache.var2 + cache.var3;
  }
};
Anim2 = new AnimMaker;

Anim3 = {
   cache:  { var1:1, var2:2, var3:3 },
   render: function(){
     var cache = this.cache;
     return cache.var1 + cache.var2 + cache.var3;
   }
};
// Now compare Anim1.render() vs Anim2.render() vs Anim3.render()
```

Using a closure is slightly faster on Chrome, twice as slow on Firefox, about the same on IE9. Caching the reference to `this.cache` as `var cache=this.cache` improves speed ever-so-slightly on some browsers. However, **the speed differences are not noticeable enough to make a noticeable impact** in any code you're writing. As shown in the results, my tests were running at hundreds of millions of lookups per second (50 million operations/second * 3 lookups per operation), much of that possibly dwarfed by the overhead of the function call.

Focus on your canvas drawing and any looping algorithms, not individual lines of code.

Comment: Awesome answer Phrogz... Huge thanks.  Some good learnings re. benchmarking for me there also.  Cheers :-)

Comment: great answer but not quite to the question that was asked. The OP seemed mostly interested in whether a local `self` variable inside of `render()` would be faster, not a closure.

Comment: @MattGreer Ah, I think you may be right. I did not understand this in my first readings. I've updated the test to include this variation. The results are that in some browsers caching the `cache` object as a local variable is a hair faster than using `this.cache` explicitly (and the closure is slightly faster on Chrome, and much slower on Firefox).